# DataTable must be set prior to using DataView. Am I binding my data the wrong way?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview, dataview

it have been a week since I start with this project but I'm totally clueless on what to fix anymore. down here is part of my coding.

```
Protected Sub bpn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
      Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer2005DBConnectionString").ToString())
        connection.Open()
        Dim sql As String = ("select * from LOT_ WHERE PRODUCTNAME ='" & txtbpn.Text & "'")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows Then
                lblerror.Visible = False
                connection.Dispose()
                connection.Close()
                Me.BindBpn()

                txtbpn.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox5.Text = String.Empty
            Else
                connection.Dispose()
                connection.Close()

                lblerror.Text = "bpn not found"
                lblerror.Visible = True
                txtbpn.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
                TextBox5.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "1;url=Summary.aspx")
    End Try
End Sub
```

1.the binding sub

```
    Private Sub BindBpn()

  Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer2005DBConnectionString").ToString())
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LOT_ WHERE PRODUCTNAME='" & txtbpn.Text & "'order by checkin asc")
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                con.Open()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Dim dv As New DataView(dt)

                GridView1.DataSource = dv
                GridView1.DataBind()
                ' Me.BindGridView()
                con.Close()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    If GridView1.Visible = False Then
        GridView1.Visible = True
    End If
    If Button1.Visible = False Then
        Button1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

2.the error happen when I'm trying to sort the data.

```
Protected Sub SortRecords(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs)

    Dim SortDir As String = String.Empty
    Dim sortExpression As String = e.SortExpression


    Dim dv As New DataView(GridView1.DataSource) 
    If dv IsNot Nothing Then
        If direction = SortDirection.Ascending Then
            direction = SortDirection.Descending

            SortDir = "Desc"
            ViewState("SortExpression") = Convert.ToString(e.SortExpression & " " & SortDir)
        Else
            direction = SortDirection.Ascending

            SortDir = "Asc"
            ViewState("SortExpression") = Convert.ToString(e.SortExpression & " " & SortDir)

        End If


    End If

    dv.Sort = ViewState("SortExpression").ToString 
    GridView1.DataSource = dv
    GridView1.DataBind()
end sub
```

The error happen on this code

```
dv.Sort = ViewState("SortExpression").ToString
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

this is my aspx GridView:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" width="100%" runat="server" 
              AllowSorting="True" 
              OnSorting="SortRecords"  
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"   
              ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="5%" />
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="LOT_ID" HeaderText="Lot ID"  />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="PkgName" HeaderText="PIN PACKAGE NAME" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="MBTBoardNo" HeaderText="MBTBoardNo" SortExpression="MBTBoardNo" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="BTProgramName" HeaderText="BT Program Name"  />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductRank" HeaderText="ProdRank"/>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="BASEPRODUCTNAME" HeaderText="BPN" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="MCNo" HeaderText="MC No" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="QTY" HeaderText="Qty" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDate" HeaderText="Start Date" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CheckIn" HeaderText="CheckIn" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CheckOut" HeaderText="CheckOut" />  
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: can you explain to me why? is it because of the sql connection? this sql connection that I put is not the actual connection . it just a random connection that I put to replace the actual connection

Comment: First of all, you must have `Option Strict Off` for that code to compile.  That's strike 1.  You should turn `Option Strict On` and fix the errors that arise first.  As for your issue, it suggests to me that `GridView1.DataSource` is `Nothing`, meaning that there is no `DataTable` backing the `DataView`. As for SQL injection, you're open to it any time you use string concatenation to insert user-entered text into your SQL code. Learn how to protect yourself with parameterised queries.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm still new with vb.net. I'll try to do the parameterised queries later.

Comment: Think carefully about what would happen if someone enters the following into txtbpn: `';DROP TABLE LOT_;--`

Comment: Also, as of two weeks ago (4/12/2016) Sql Server 2005 has reached it's end of life. It no longer gets any patches or updates... not even critical security fixes. It's irresponsible and dangerous to continue using it. The time to upgrade is **now**.  ... check that. The time to upgrade was _six months ago._

Comment: okay Thanks for your help and respond @JoelCoehoorn . I've already check other thread regarding the parameterised queries and it's really helpful for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be overkill butI need to explain some things.

Sql injection attacks aside for the moment you have a lot of other thing to understand first.

1. You are having trouble sorting because you have not Cached the retrieved data to any persistence mechanism.  This Code in your sorting mechanism will always evaluate to Nothing:

   `Dim dv As New DataView(GridView1.DataSource)`
2. A GridView DataSource is not persisted across postbacks unless you
   use a Caching data control like `SqlDataSource` which manages the
   cache for you.
3. Or you do so programmatically in one of:

   1. ViewState(bad idea)
   2. SessionState(not perfect)
   3. the Application Cache(ideal)

But back to basics:

Here is an edited and annotated version of the first part of your post
I'll provide a cleaned up version following this:

```
Protected Sub bpn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  ' Added for clarity
  Dim cs as String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer2005DBConnectionString").ToString()
  ' Try is generally not needed if you are using Using
  ' at least not here. Move it to the inner most Using block and 
  ' wrap it around the actual command execution to catch sql errors
  ' you want to personally manage.

  ' Try   

  Using connection As New SqlConnection(cs)
      connection.Open()
     ' String.Format() - learn to love this function 
     Dim sql As String = String.Format("select * from LOT WHERE PRODUCTNAME ='{0}' order by checkin asc", txtbpn.Text)

     Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

       ' This reader is not necessary as all you are doing 
       ' is using it to determine if there is anything to do
       ' This is a waste of time
       ' You already have one open connection and 
       ' now you are jumping to a bind operation 
       ' that opens more. 
       ' Generally speaking: 
       '   open a data connection, get the data, close the connection
       Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

         ' Do this here, not in both parts of the `If`
         lblerror.Visible = reader.HasRows

         ' lblerror.Text can be initialized here or in the .aspx 
         ' as you do nothing else with it but toggle its visibility
         ' Plus you can make use of a GridView's EmptyDataText property
         ' and get rid of the Label altogether.
         lblerror.Text = "bpn not found"

         If reader.HasRows Then

             Me.BindBpn() 

         End If

         ' This code is not needed as it's handled by the outer Using
         ' connection.Dispose()
         ' connection.Close()

         // Since this code happens in both parts of the 
         // IF, it only needs to happen once.
         txtbpn.Text = String.Empty
         TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
         TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
         TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
         TextBox5.Text = String.Empty

      // Check your original code: 2 Using requires 2 End Using  
      End Using
    End Using
  ' See Try above
  Catch ex As Exception
      Response.Write(ex.Message)

      'Why are you trying to refresh every second?
      Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "1;url=Summary.aspx")
  End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the Revised Code without all the comments

```
Protected Sub bpn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim cs as String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer2005DBConnectionString").ToString()
  Using connection As New SqlConnection(cs)
     connection.Open()
     Dim sql As String = String.Format("select * from LOT WHERE PRODUCTNAME ='{0}' order by checkin asc", txtbpn.Text)

     Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

     Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter( cmd )
        Try
          Dim dt As New DataTable()
          sda.Fill(dt)
          Dim dv as New DataView(dt)

          ' This will persist the retrieved record set
          ' -- Replaced C# syntax with VB 
          Cache("AStringToIdentifyThisGridviewCache") = dv
          GridView1.DataSource = Cache("AStringToIdentifyThisGridviewCache")

          Gridview1.EmptyDataText = "bpn not found"
          GridView1.DataBind()
          GridView1.Visible = (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)

          txtbpn.Text = String.Empty
          TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
          TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
          TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
          TextBox5.Text = String.Empty

        Catch ex As Exception
          Gridview1.EmptyDataText = ex.Message
        End Try

     End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

One more thing, your data is going to be retrieved from the database and will overwrite the Cache and rebind to the GridView every time you hit the button.

Typically you want to retrieve the data once and then work with the Cached dataset until the data is modified in some way that it requires another database hit.

Programmatic data retrieval and binding is certainly useful, but I find I rarely need to use it. You may be under requirements for this project but for GridView operations, it's hard to beat the provided DataSource Controls.

Hope this helps.
Happy Coding.

### Sorting Code lifted from MSDN Sample for GridView Sorting

```
  Protected Sub SortRecords(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs)

    'Retrieve the table from the session object.
    Dim dv As DataView = TryCast(Cache("AStringToIdentifyThisGridviewCache"), DataView)

    If dv IsNot Nothing Then
        'Sort the data.
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression)
        GridView1.DataSource = Cache("AStringToIdentifyThisGridviewCache")
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End If

  End Sub


  Private Function GetSortDirection(ByVal column As String) As String

    ' By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
    Dim sortDirection = "ASC"

    ' Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
    Dim sortExpression = TryCast(ViewState("SortExpression"), String)

    If sortExpression IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Check if the same column is being sorted.
        ' Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
        If sortExpression = column Then
            Dim lastDirection = TryCast(ViewState("SortDirection"), String)
            If lastDirection IsNot Nothing _
              AndAlso lastDirection = "ASC" Then

                sortDirection = "DESC"

            End If
        End If
    End If

    ' Save new values in ViewState.
    ViewState("SortDirection") = sortDirection
    ViewState("SortExpression") = column

    Return sortDirection

  End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply . I 've already tried using  your revised code but I'm getting new error 'Column ColumnName cant be found'. would you mind helping me fixing that?

Comment: And can you post the GridView markup? Where is ColumnName being defined - I don't see it in any existing code

Comment: the error occured when I write 


Dim dt As New DataTable(GridView1.DataSource)


but when I'm using dataview instead of datatable like

Dim dv as New DataView(GridView1.datasource)

the same error(the error that happen in my main question) still occur

it occur on this line

dv.Sort = ViewState("SortExpression").ToString

Comment: I copied the code into a webforms project and I spotted a couple of syntax errors where I mixed C# with the VB - i'll fix the errors here.  But after fixing the errors the button populates the GridView with my test data.  I don't get a ColumnName error - can you edit your post to include your GridView Markup?  in the mean time i'm looking into your sorting code

Comment: I'm sorry. wdy mean by the gridview markup? do you mean the aspx code?

Comment: I took the sorting code from an [MSDN Sample GridView here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and replaced their Session Variable with the Cache("") that I used above.  It's a good piece of code to look over to see how they manage sorting programmatically.

Comment: I edited your post to only show the GridView and edited out the styling.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There isnt any error any more. thanks a lot.